# Custom Model URL

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there currently (in the latest builds) a way of specifying a URL on a model-by-model basis? in Ember Data 1.0 beta? I have found some questions on SO and issues on Github around this, but most are out-dated.

For example, I have a model that's called `App.PaymentSearchResult` and rather than having the request go to `/payment_search_results` I would like it to go to `/payments/search`. Where would I override the URL used for a given model (rather than overriding `buildURL` on the `RESTAdapter`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the the find adapter
 but it's kind of hackish, i think however i would take another approach. Idealy you want your Ember models to reflect your backend's models, so why would you need a PaymentSearchResult? When you probably already have a Payment model?

If you need to search in your payment records, why not handle it using query params?
http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/#toc_querying-for-records

```
this.store.find('payment', { total: "22" });
```

Then you want to answer accordingly on the server.

If you want to do a search which returns multiple models, you do this with a manual ajax request.

```
var self = this;
$.get( "/search", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(result) {
   self.store.pushMany(result);
});
```

PushMany assumes a sane JSON structure.
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushMany

Comment: The reason I have two models is that my 'payment' model is rather complex (it's not actually a payment, that was just for illustration). My PaymentSearchResult is simply a partial representation of the other model. I decided to go this way because ED currently does not seem to have a good way of keeping track of partial data.